# Error in catkin_ws

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone!!

Tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote

When use:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/
wstool set humanoid_msgs --git https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs
```

Get this error:

```
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.
```

I created the catkin_ws according to http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

A lot of thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191130/error-in-catkin_ws/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-08-24**:
Did you make sure that the command *source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash* is executed every time you open a new terminal?

You should add *source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash* to the file *~/.bashrc*

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-26**:
A lot of Thanks!!!

Do you know what the folder I have to keep "humanoid_msgs"

Is in ~/catkin_ws/src?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Continue the same problem:

```
~/catkin_ws/src$ wstool set humanoid_msgs --git https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.
> ```

In addition to the comment of @Martin Peris: afaik the `cwd` needs to be the directory containing the `.rosinstall` file. Alternatively, you need to provide the `-t WORKSPACE` or `--target-workspace=WORKSPACE` argument to point `wstool` to the proper directory.

For your particular situation (with the `cwd` being `~/catking_ws`), this would be:

```
wstool set --target-workspace=src humanoid_msgs --git https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs
```

---

Edit:

@vncntmh wrote:

> Get this error:
>
> ```
> ERROR in config: /home/vincent/src has no workspace configuration file '.rosinstall'
> ```

Ah, so your source space hasn't been initialised by `wstool`. First do:

```
wstool init ~/catking_ws/src
```

then the `wstool set ..` should succeed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Used:

```
 wstool set ~/catkin_ws/src humanoid_msgs --git https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs
 Error: Too many arguments.
 wstool set [localname] [SCM-URI]?  [--(svn|hg|git|bzr)] [--version=VERSION]]
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-26**:
Your commandline doesn't make sense: you're missing the `--target-workspace` argument.

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-26**:
So, How is?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-26**:
Does the example command line from my initial answer not work for you?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Get this error:

```
ERROR in config: /home/vincent/src has no workspace configuration file '.rosinstall'
```

**Comment by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on 2016-02-16**:
wstool set ~/catkin_ws/src humanoid_msgs --git https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs

```
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.
```

Same problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-16**:
You're *also* missing the `-t` option. Also: make sure that `~/catkin_ws/src` already contains a `.rosinstall` file, or it won't work.